# Spec($A$) is connected if $A$ is local

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Another exercise from Balwant-Singh:

Show that if $A$ is local then Spec($A$) is connected in the Zariski topology.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible hint: a local ring $R$ have a unique maximal ideal $m$. For every *proper ideal* $I \lhd R$ we must have $m \in V(I)$ hence every openset $m \not \in D(I)$, for $I$ proper ideal.

Comment: I have understood your argument, but what do you mean by $D(I)$ ?

Comment: @WLOG Right I supposed that it was well known notation: $D(I) = Spec(R) \setminus V(I)$ a standard open set.